# Explanation of "зарыта" in "Вот где собака зарыта"

Tags: одним-словом, idioms

The expression *"Вот где собака зарыта"* can be translated, as far as I know, as *(that is) where the shoe pinches*. The literal translation, of course, doesn't match.

So far, my literal (vague) translation amounts to *"there is where the dog buries (something)"*, making reference to an issue that was hidden and suddenly emerges.

I cannot find what kind of word is **зарыта**, though. That is, it seems to be derived from the verb *bury*, "зарыть" as lingvo, wiktionary and gramota point out.  But what kind of word is **зарыта**? it doesn't seem to be a conjugation of *зарыть*, and if so my apologies for not finding it.

Comment: краткая форма отглагольного прилагательного "зарытый" в женском роде

Comment: @КуЪ, А почему не пассивный залог?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`зарытa` is the *passive voice* of the verb `зарыть`, present tense, feminine. So it literally means "buried".  This is similar to `закрыта` from `закрыть` or `залита` from `залить`.

The adjective would be `зарытая`.

Comment: It is definitely past tense. In present it would be "зарываема".

Comment: `зарываема` is from `зарывать`, i. e. imperfective aspect.  `зарыть` is perfective aspect. And this is present tense. `была зарыта` is past tense, and `будет зарыта` is future.

Answer (score 3):

The literal translation is "That's where the dog is buried," and the meaning is "This is the core of the issue" or "That's where the answer is."

Comment: and зарыта is ... ?

Comment: зарыта is buried

Comment: @EugeneS yes, thanks, I could infer that. But nothing ensures me that after translating "buried" back to Russian I get the same conjugation of the verb (sometimes it cannot exist at all, e.g. translating strictly literally into German the phrase "I'm doing *X*-thing" is impossible.) So I was rather asking about the *exact kind of word*.

Answer (score 2):

As @ruskie.info and @Eugene S have [written](https://russian.stackexchange.com/a/2152/560), "зарыта" means buried. It's an adjective derived from the verb "to bury" and it is declined regularly:

Singular:

- я зарыт
- ты зарыт
- он зарыт/**она зарыта**/оно зарыто

Plural:

- мы зарыты
- вы зарыты
- они зарыты

Comment: I think you are conjugating here, rather than declining.